# Evaluating multiple variables with ng-class in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have an object like this:

```
{{blockParameters}}
{"courseid":"1","blockid":"2"}
```

I want to add an ng-class example like below:

```
ng-class="{blockParameters.courseid == 1 && blockParameters.blockid == 2 : 'active'}"
```

That gives a syntax error, i'm not sure on the correct way to do it.

Comment: what does the error say, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the other way around: class name first, then expression:

```
ng-class="{active: blockParameters.courseid === '1' && blockParameters.courseid === '2'}"
```

When using `{}` notation in ngClass think of it as an ordinary javascript expression. Would your original syntax make valid JS object? No, that's why you get error.

Comment: I know double equal sign works, but is it the best practice is triple euqal?

Comment: I prefer strict comparison `===`.

Comment: Same, that's why I think your solution should change to `===`

Comment: Also keep in mind that if your class names have a '-' in them, you need to wrap the classname in " " as a String.

Comment: There is no syntax error but it doesn't apply the class

Comment: @Jordash Check  `{{ blockParameters.courseid === '1' && blockParameters.courseid === '2' }}`. Is it true or false?

Comment: Yeah that worked, it was because both variables were the same `courseid` just had to switch out one of them with `blockid`

Answer (score 2):

ScotchIO has a [wonderful tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass) covering all the common ways to use ng-class.

In your case like dfsq has mentioned you want to notate it (except with strict equality):

```
ng-class="{active: blockParameters.courseid == 1 && blockParameters.courseid == 2}"
```

If you read the tutorial you will quickly learn that if you have class names like `.some-class-name` with a `-` in the name, you will need to wrap the class name as a string:

```
ng-class="{'active-class': blockParameters.courseid == 1 && blockParameters.courseid == 2}"
```